# how to make element like <Preference> from PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-button

Looking for an easy way to make element `<Preference>` from `PreferenceScreen`, but don't need to use it in `PreferenceActivity` (i want, for example within `DialogFragment`).

Something like that:
[DialogFragment from my dream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTjHK.png)

Maybe exist  a button that looks just like `<Preference>` element. Thanks for any answer.

Comment: that image is an `AlertDialog` with a title

Comment: But i can't inflate `<Preference>` element in non-PreferenceActivity. Or am I wrong?